# Improving The Computation time of a recursive numerical method

Tags: numerics, recursion

I am trying to do a recursive numerical method to solve an ODE in Mathematica. Whatever I try, I cannot get the computation time down. I need to do over 1000 steps, but I cannot get even 20 steps within a reasonable amount of time. I have been reading and attempting "Memoization" and using nest, but they aren't doing well because I have three values. Can someone help me get better time on this? One of the recursive functions I have is as follows:

```
    Timing[
         h = .01;
         f[x_] := Dot[{{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}, x];
         wp[0] := {0, 1};
         wp[1] = wp[0] + h*f[wp[0]];
         wp[2] = wp[1] + h*f[wp[1]];
         wp[n_] := wp[n - 1] + (h/12) (23*f[wp[n - 1]] - 16*f[wp[n - 2]] + 5 f{wp[n - 3]]);
          ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memoization is the way to go here. Your problem is that when Mathematica sees `wp[1000]`, it will rewrite it using your rule for `wp[n_]`, and then it will try to evaluate `wp[999]`, `wp[998]`, and `wp[997]`. But each of those evaluations depend on, e.g., `wp[996]`, and so Mathematica will end up evaluating `wp[996]` three times. This ends up exploding combinatorially: think about how many times Mathematica would evaluate `wp[500]`, for example.

You need to tell Mathematica that once it evaluates `wp[996]`, or any value of `wp`, then it's done: any time it sees `wp[996]` again, it should spit out the same value without thinking. This is what `=`, rather than `:=` is for: when Mathematica sees `=`, it evaluates the right hand side once, and saves it as the value of the left hand side, never going through a long evaluation again.

So in summary: to use this "memoization" procedure on a rule like `f[x_] := rhs`, just write `f[x_] := f[x] = rhs`. The first time Mathematica sees `f[x]`, it will evaluate `rhs`, then save that value as `f[x]` and use that value any time it sees `f[x]` in the future.

```
Timing[h = .01;
 f[x_] := Dot[{{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}, x];
 wp[0] := {0, 1};
 wp[1] = wp[0] + h*f[wp[0]];
 wp[2] = wp[1] + h*f[wp[1]];
 wp[n_] := 
  wp[n] = wp[
     n - 1] + (h/12) (23*f[wp[n - 1]] - 16*f[wp[n - 2]] + 
       5 f[wp[n - 3]]);
 wp[1000]
 ]
```

gives `{0.03125, {-0.544073, -0.839153}}`.

Comment: You have saved my life